# Changes in Primal and Dual Solutions When Scaled

Tags: linear-programming

Suppose that we have an LP in the standard form 
$$\text{(P) min  }c^Tx: Ax=b,  x\le 0$$ 
and it's dual would be 
$$\text{(D) max  }b^Tx: Ax\le c$$ 
Let $\overline{x}$ and $\overline{y}$ be the optimal solutions to (P) and (D) respectively. 
 
 
How do these solutions change if we multiply the constraint $Ax=b$ by a scalar? I think we'd have the following 
$$\text{(P$\alpha$) min  }c^Tx: \alpha Ax=b,  x\le 0$$ 
and it's dual would be 
$$\text{(D$\alpha$) max  }b^Tx: \alpha Ax\le c$$ 
Where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ 
My initial thoughts are that
1. The optimal value's of (P), (D), (P$\alpha$), and (D$\alpha$) won't change since the feasible region wont' change.
2. The optimal solutions will just be $\overline{x}/\alpha$ and $\overline{y}/\alpha$ for (P$\alpha$) and (D$\alpha$) respectively.
Yet, this seems wrong. 
I'm rather new to Linear Programming and duality and would love an explanation of why my intuition is/isn't correct.

Answer (score 2):

We would have

$$\text{(P$\alpha$) min  }c^Tx: \alpha Ax=\color{blue}\alpha b,  x\le 0$$ 
and it's dual would be 
$$\text{(D$\alpha$) max  }\color{blue}{\alpha}b^Tx: \alpha Ax\le c$$ 
Where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$

The primal solution would remain the same since the feasible set remains the same. The corresponding dual solution would be $\frac1{\alpha}\bar{y}$.

Comment: For (P$\alpha$) why would you multiply b by $\alpha$? Wouldn't that make $\alpha Ax=\alpha b$ equivalent to $Ax=b$?

Comment: That is what the question meant right? Multiplying the constraint $Ax=b$ by a scalar. not just multiplying each row of $A$ by $\alpha$. Yes, they are equivalent.

Comment: My mistake, I meant $\overline{A}_i=\alpha*A_i$. Where $\overline{A}$ represents the modified primal constraint

Comment: you probably mean $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$